# What are the difference between "prominent" and "VIP"?

Tags: differences

The definition of prominent and VIP are same: an important person

So if I say: Mai is a prominent guy of Australia

OR

Mai is a V.I.P. of Australia.

Isn't the meaning is the same?

---

**Research:**

Definition of *VIP* by [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vip):

> very important person.

Definition of *prominent* by [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prominent):

> leading, important, or well-known:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, *VIP* is used to indicate that the person should be given special privileges. It may be because they're famous (which would make them *prominent*), but it could also be just because they're rich and expected to spend more money. For instance, a gentleman's club or casino might have a VIP Room, where rich patrons can have privacy.

There's quite a bit of overlap, but *prominent* describes the person's position in society, while *VIP* refers to how they're treated by specific groups or in certain situations. At a wedding, the bride and groom, as well as their families, are VIPs; the next day, they're just ordinary people.

Comment: _At a wedding, the bride and groom, as well as their families are VIPs;..._ They can also be prominent isn't it? _At a wedding, the bride and groom, as well as their families are prominent;..._

Comment: @XPMai- THIS is a really good answer!

Comment: True, they're also prominent, since they're sitting at the head table and the bride is probably wearing a white gown that stands out among the rest. But they'll also be VIPs during preparation, when there aren't any other guests to compare them to. And their honeymoon resort might treat them as VIPs because they're staying in the honeymoon suite, but no one else would recognize them as prominent.

Answer (score 0):

They can be used similarly, but "prominent" has a broader scope.

*Prominent* usually refers to a very public figure (and often uses the word "figure"):

"Mai is a prominent person/figure *in* Australia."

*V.I.P.* is usually used within an organization, or a more localized setting:

"Mai is a V.I.P. among bankers in Sydney."

Comment: 'Prominent' by definition is something which sticks out e.g. *he has a prominent ear lobe*. If this chap *Mai* is so 'prominent' does he not have a surname? Or is Mai his surname? Australia is an Angolspheric country which observes the usual convention of Christian and surnames. But using terms like VIP and 'prominent' always strikes me as a lazy way of not bothering to find out what the person actually does.

Comment: @WS2 - Lazy... or there are allegations which if mentioned could find one being fitted for cement galoshes.

Comment: There is clearly something in the profundity of your comment which escapes me!

Comment: Hmm... Did you see "The Godfather..?"

Comment: So long ago I've forgotten. But, seriously, you wouldn't expect someone to announce 'a prominent American will be arriving tonight', would you? Wouldn't you expect a bit more detail? Why should it be any different with an Australian?

Comment: It seems prominent is a consequence of being a VIP.

Comment: It is one of those words that is vastly overused. I tend to reserve it for things like *he had a prominent carbuncle on the left side of his chin*.

Comment: Was it named Rockefeller?

Comment: I feel you guys are off-topic. @WS2, why related to religions/countries while it was just an example? | Oldbag, why related to cement and godfather while I am consulting about English definition? | I am really confused.

Comment: @XPMai- A comment was made that it was lazy to use "prominent" instead of finding out what the person does to make them important, and saying that. My comment meant that not all prominent people actually work for a living, (some inherited wealth or status) and some would not want it mentioned. (High-profile criminals) Since NY City consists mainly of islands, it was fairly common to make a person disappear by dumping them in a body of water. Casting cement around the feet, keeps the corpse from floating and evidence being discovered. ("Cement overshoes/galoshes")

Comment: @XPMai We have perhaps done you less than justice here (though I am puzzled to see where I may have mentioned religion). *Prominent* does say much the same thing as *V.I.P*.Personally I don't care for either term. I like to find out what the person does and say they are *the greatest living expert on cabbage-white butterflies* or whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

*[**VIP**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=VIP&searchmode=none)* is an acronym for ***[v](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/vip?q=VIP#VIP)***ery **i**mportant **p**erson.

> NOUN
>
> A very important person:

The phrase does not indicate to whom or for what reason the person is important.

The definition for ***prominent*** contains the word *important* too:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1. Important; famous:

So they share a semantic field.

The etymology of ***[prominent](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=prominent&searchmode=none)*** suggests why important people tend to be given prominent positions: mentally, physically, and organizationally.

> mid-15c., "*projecting*, *jutting out*,"
>
> from Latin *prominentem* (nominative *prominens*) "*prominent*," present
>   participle of *prominere* "*jut* or *stand out*, *be prominent*, *overhang*,"
>
> from *pro*- "*before*, *forward*" (see pro-) + *minere* "*to project*,"
>
> from *minae* "*projections*, *threats*" (see menace (n.)).
>
> Meaning "conspicuous" is from 1759;
>
> that of "notable, leading" is from 1849.

**Mentally**, the phrase: *He puts his pants on one leg at a time* is an accommodation for the mental *prominence* we tend to give important people. Their great accomplishments demonstrate superior power, and that power tends to intimidate, as the ***threat*** connotation of the etymology suggests. We try to bring them down a notch in our minds, but the mental intimidation of their *prominence* remains.

**Physically**, they sit at the head table at banquets, and abide on the top floor of the corporate headquarters as demonstrations of their *importance*.

**Organizationally** they sit at the top of the chart. Every one within the organization is expected to defer to the *prominent* agenda of the VIPs, who also become the *prominent* face and persona to everyone outside the organization.

All of that *prominence* is projected **because** a person has done something that makes him a *very important person* in the organization. By extension of the organization's *importance*, she becomes a *very important person* in a broader context.

Very *important* people tend to be very *prominent* people.